# Adding white space in SASS declaration

Tags: css, variables, sass, unicode, dart-sass

I'm trying to produce the following SASS code, using a variable that stores the  weight for a variable font:

```
$normal-font: 335;

:root {
   font-weight: $normal-font;
   font-variation-settings: "wght" #{$normal-font};
}
```

The CSS result (using dart-sass) needs to be:

```
:root {
   font-weight: 335;
   font-variation-settings: "wght" 335;
}
```

Instead, the white space between the two components is being stripped by the processor and I'm getting:

```
:root {
   font-weight: 335;
   font-variation-settings: "wght"335;
}
```

Nothing I've tried achieves the desired result.  Inserting the unicode "\0020", for some reason produces:

```
font-variation-settings: "wght"\ 335
```

while `font-variation-settings: "wght" " " #{$normal-font}` wraps the white space in quotes:

```
font-variation-settings: "wght"" "335
```

If I try to remove those quotes using `unquote`, like this  `font-variation-settings: "wght" unquote(" ") #{$normal-font}`, the resulting CSS strips the white space out:

```
font-variation-settings: "wght"335;
```

No combination of the above techniques seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are writing SASS, dont use the Root declaration. When using root, use variables like this: --normal-font: 335. You dont want to mix SASS and CSS variables